# How to reverse order of results in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i've just started learing javascript, and i'm wondering if you could help me print out the order of results here in reverse order?

```
for (var x=1; x<= 10; x++) {
    if ( x % 2 == 0 ) {
        document.write(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: for (var x = 10; x >= 1; x--)

Comment: do you really want to ignore the first item (0-based index) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reverse your loop by initializing `x` to 10 and decreasing it with `x--`.

```js
for (var x = 10; x >= 1; x--) {
    if ( x % 2 == 0 ) {
        document.write(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either x > 0 or x >= 1 as he starts with 1 initially

Comment: @dejakob well spotted :)

Comment: @Kalphos can you validate my answer if it's ok for you?

Comment: Yep I just need to wait 1 minute :o)

Answer (score 0):

`var x=10;` is the startpoint of the loop, `x>=1` is where the loop should stop, and `x--` is the number which should decrement:

```js
for (var x=10; x>= 1; x--) {
    if ( x % 2 == 0 ) {
        console.log(x);
    }
}
```

It could also look more simple like(without using an if statement):

```js
for (var x = 10; x >= 1; x -= 2) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even Better.

```js
for (var x = 10; x > 0; x = x - 2) {
  document.write(x + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];
  for (var x=1; x<= 10; x++) {
    if ( x % 2 == 0 ) {
      result.push(x)
    }
  }
result.reverse(); // reverse the order of the elements in an array
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i ++){
   document.write(result[i]);
}
```

Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

```
var res=0;
for (var x=1; x<= 10; x++) {
    if ( x % 2 == 0 ) {
        res=res+x;
    }
}
```

There are many ways to reverse the given string.One of the way.

```
   //Assuming res contains hello.
1. var splitString = res.split(""); // var splitString = "hello".split("");
    // ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

    // Step 2. Use the reverse() method to reverse the new created array
    var reverseArray = splitString.reverse(); // var reverseArray = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"].reverse();
    // ["o", "l", "l", "e", "h"]

    // Step 3. Use the join() method to join all elements of the array into a string
    var joinArray = reverseArray.join(""); // var joinArray = ["o", "l", "l", "e", "h"].join("");
    // "olleh"

    //Step 4. Return the reversed string
    return joinArray; // "olleh"
```

Now joinArray contains the result of the reversed input.